# AWS EMR luigi pipeline generates $folder$ temp files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, luigi

I have a `luigi` pipeline that I run on `AWS EMR`. In the `luigi.cfg` config file I have no such source or destination files, but in `S3` bucket I see these `{some_name}_$folder$` files for each output folder (in output path) and files themselves. Since I have many pipeline runs with many files these weird `_$folder$` accumulate in large quantities and it becomes an issue. How to prevent `AWS` from outputting them? I could run additional script maybe to delete them but it does not look like how it should be done.

Comment: Its not recommended to delete `_$folder$` https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-s3-empty-files/

This is part of `S3NativeFileSystem`
`public static final String FOLDER_SUFFIX = "_$folder$";`